# define `fori` macro / function in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to be able to loop through a collection but maintain a counter with that loop.  I managed to create e.g.

```
(for [[email i] (map vector emails (range))]
  ...)
```

to do this, but ideally I'd prefer a `fori` macro (unless a function is possible but my gut says it's gotta be a macro) that lets me do equivalently

```
(fori [email i emails]
  ...)
```

or

```
(fori [[email i] emails]
  ...)
```

I've no experience with macros, and looking at the source for the `for` macro it looks pretty intimidating.  Any help?

Super-cool would be a macro that follows the `for` syntax and allows e.g.

```
(fori [email i emails
       line j (lines email)]
  ...)
```

Comment: @KobbyPemson OK, that'd be halfway there, but still more repetition than I want since I'm doing this over emails, tweets, mms's, facebooks, wordpresses, tumblrs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a macro that expands to `for`, but I'm not really convinced there's much point. There are numerous built-ins for exactly this purpose, and the `fori` syntax doesn't really read very well. At the very least it should look like

```
(fori [[email i] emails, 
       [line j] (lines email)]
  ...)
```

But if you really wanted to write it exactly as you said, it's certainly not impossible:

```
(defmacro fori [bindings body]
  (letfn [(clauses [bindings]
            (lazy-seq
              (cond (empty? bindings) ()
                    (keyword? (first bindings)) (concat (take 2 bindings)
                                                        (clauses (drop 2 bindings)))
                    :else (let [[name index value] (take 3 bindings)]
                            (list* [index name] `(map-indexed vector ~value)
                                   (clauses (drop 3 bindings)))))))]
    `(for [~@(clauses bindings)]
       ~body)))

user> (macroexpand-1 '(fori [email i xs, 
                             :when (even? i)
                             line j (lines email)]
                        [i line]))
(for [[i email] (map-indexed vector xs)
      :when (even? i)
      [j line] (map-indexed vector (lines email))]

  [i line])
```

Comment: Primary goal was an equivalent to `Seq.iteri` from F# land; this goes even beyond that which is great, though ultimately I agree the format you offered is probably better; I'll look through this and figure out how to modify it.

Comment: For anyone else looking for the syntax suggested at the top of the answer, it ended up being pretty simple: modify the `let` to `[[[name index] value] (take 2 bindings)]` and then `(drop 2 bindings)` at the end.

Comment: Or looking at it more and generally agreeing that a `fori` *expression* is probably further than you'd want to take this pattern, a simple `fori` that will work in the single-loop case is: (defmacro fori [[[item i] collection] body] `(for [[~i ~item] (map-indexed vector ~collection)] ~body))

Comment: @DaxFohl "fori expression"? Since Clojure doesn't have any statements I am not sure what this means.

Comment: @noisesmith my comment is in the lexicon of F#; sequence *expressions* vs regular functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn fori [coll]
  (map-indexed (fn [idx itm] [idx itm]) coll))
```

Is probably what you want. e.g.

```
(fori [:a :b :c :d])
```

produces

```
([0 :a] [1 :b] [2 :c] [3 :d])
```

BTW, for is not a loop but creates a list comprehension. If you're looking to do something with side effects inside a loop you should look into doseq.

Comment: Isn't that just equivalent to `(def fori map-indexed)`, or basically telling me to use `map-indexed`?  In which case see my first comment to the question.

Comment: No, it's not equivalent. Try it.

Comment: Okay, same as `(def fori (partial map-indexed vector))`. Looking for more.